# What's the difference between regexec and pcre_exec?

Tags: c++, c, regex, pcre

I have a pattern

> ```
> "^\+?\d{3,20}$"
> ```

- Test on "`123455`", "`+123445`",  expected match.
- Test on "`123+213`", "`abc`", expect no match.

This pattern worked on `pcre_exec()` but not on `regexec()`.

Comment: Note that the `\d` in the string is not a valid C string literal; `\d` is not a defined escape sequence.  Your compiler should be warning you about that.  You'd need to write `\\d` in the string literal to get `\d` to the regex compilation function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`regexec()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html) function implements [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) and Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

The [`pcre_exec()`](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/) function implements [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](http://pcre.org/), which are a major superset of the ERE (see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for Perl's specification of Perl's REs).

The `\d` notation is not special to POSIX ERE (let alone BRE); it does not mean 'a digit'.  It does mean 'a digit' in PCRE.  If you want the regular expression to work in both dialects, you'll need to use `[0-9]` in place of `\d`, and ensure `regcomp()` is told to compile an ERE.

```
"^+?[0-9]{3,20}$"
```